# Button Class Get not the full length of div?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have tried to give the full length of div . But button could not get the full length . Please help me to fix out the errors.

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center card">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">  
     <span class="icon">
        <img src="{{ URL::asset('frontAssets/assets/images/classroutine1.png')}}" 
             alt="Classroutine" style="width:50%; 
             height: 93.3px; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 25px">
      </span>
      <div style=" padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 20px">
            <h3>Class <br> Routine</h3> 
       </div>
   </button>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Add `width:100%` to `block` class or as a style in the button.

Comment: It's not work. And button class be btn btn-primary.

Comment: Add this: `.card{ padding:0px}`

Answer (score 1):

Because in bootstrap, the column have `padding-right: 15px;` and `padding-left: 15px;` by default. So if you want your button to get the full width of the column, you can overwrite these css or add the css below to your button:

Demo:

```css
.block {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center card">
  <button type="button" class="block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">  
     <span class="icon">
        <img src="{{ URL::asset('frontAssets/assets/images/classroutine1.png')}}" 
             alt="Classroutine" style="width:50%; 
             height: 93.3px; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 25px">
      </span>
      <div style=" padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 20px">
            <h3>Class <br> Routine</h3> 
       </div>
   </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to update css:

```css
.card {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.block {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And the button has already taken full width of parent `div`, if you want to make `div` wider, try to adjust bootstrap column size, for example `col-md-3` to `col-md-6`:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-center card">
```

Answer (score 1):

All Bootstrap columns (`.col-*`) have padding-x (`padding-right: 15px;` and `padding-left: 15px;`) by default.

If the button is the only child element of that column, and you don't want to override the class's styles, you can use the `px-0` or `p-0` class on the column to override the padding of *only* that column:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center card px-0">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use display: inline-block in both "span" and next "div" tag.

Answer (score 1):

Remove padding to the column div:

```
.card{ padding:0px}
```

Here is the snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
      .card{ padding:0px}
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center card">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">  
     <span class="icon">
        <!-- <img src="{{ URL::asset('frontAssets/assets/images/classroutine1.png')}}" 
             alt="Classroutine" style="width:50%; 
             height: 93.3px; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 25px"> -->
      </span>
      <div style=" padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 20px">
            <h3>Class <br> Routine</h3> 
       </div>
   </button>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center card">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="width:100%">  
     <span class="icon">
        <img src="{{ URL::asset('frontAssets/assets/images/classroutine1.png')}}" 
             alt="Classroutine" style="width:50%; 
             height: 93.3px; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 25px">
      </span>
      <div style=" padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 20px">
            <h3>Class <br> Routine</h3> 
       </div>
   </button>
</div>
```

Use **width:100%** as style or add it in any class and then apply that class to the button

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use padding zero .

```
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center card px-0" style="padding: 0px ">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#classRoutine" style="width:100%">  
         <span class="icon">
            <img src="{{ URL::asset('frontAssets/assets/images/classroutine1.png')}}" 
                 alt="Classroutine" style="width:50%; 
                 height: 93.3px; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 25px">
          </span>
          <div style=" padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 20px">
                <h3>Class <br> Routine</h3> 
           </div>
       </button>
     </div>
```